# Apache Camel JMS with ActiveMQ: Sending Messages with Dynamic Priority

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, priority-queue

I am currently implementing a Java messaging system with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ. My goal is to dynamically set the priority of a message based on a few attributes the message has.

I already configured my ActiveMQ as explained [here](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues). Then I created the following method that sends a `TextMessage`:

```java
public void send(BaseMessage baseMessage, int jmsPriority) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<String, Object> messageHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    messageHeaders.put(MESSAGING_HEADER_JMS_PRIORITY, jmsPriority);
    messageHeaders.put(MESSAGING_HEADER_TYPE, baseMessage.getClass().getSimpleName());
    String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(baseMessage);
    producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(payload, messageHeaders);
}
```

Sending the message perfectly works, and the dynamic type of `BaseMessage` is properly set to the header of each message. The priority is set as well, but is ignored. The order for the outcoming messages is still FIFO, as queues usually do.

Until now I did not achieve to set the priority of the message dynamically. I do not want to use Apache Camel's Resequencer since I would have to create several new queues only for "sorting". From my point of view ActiveMQ must be able to prioritize and reorder the messages itself.

Any tip is appreciated. Ask me for further details if required.

Comment: Did you enable the "preserveMessageQos" option on your endpoint to take account of the provided priority ? Camel doc says "Set to true, if you want to send message using the QoS settings specified on the message, instead of the QoS settings on the JMS endpoint"

Comment: Camel's ProducerTemplate just sets or overrides the default JMS priority of 4. As you mentioned, I would like to set the priority somehow you would do it on the interface `javax.jms.Message` interface. I stopped all consumers and sent messages with priority from 1 to 9 and then started the consumers again. The messages where consumed from 1 to 9 (FIFO) instead of 9 to 1 (expected behavior from priority queue).

Comment: @TacheDeChoco yes I did so. I also tried setting `explicitQosEnabled` to true. Same behavior unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

By default, ActiveMQ disables message priority. This is normal. When doing distributed messaging-- sending messages across servers, prioritization does not practically work out, since the broker can only scan so many messages in the queue for messages of a higher priority before it stats to slow down all traffic for that queue.

Prioritized messages can work well when embedding a broker and using it for task dispatch-- where queue depth generally doesn't exceed the low-thousands.

Updated:

Reminder-- the QOS settings in JMS *must* be set on the MessageProducer object, and *not* the message per JMS-spec.

[Enable Prioritized Messages](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues)

Comment: I know it is disabled by default, but I activated it intentionally and still, there is no reordering of the messages on the broker server.

Comment: Please share your code-- see my update. With JMS, the priority *must* be set on the MessageProducer object, and not the Message class. Per-JMS spec

Comment: Asking for a friend.. if you vote -1 on an answer, it'd be helpful to get a comment explaining the reasoning behind the -1.